# after power breaks, gparted / fdisk reports that ssd disk has incorrect table. How to fix it

Tags: ssd, fdisk, gdisk

After power breaks, gparted / fdisk reports that ssd disk has incorrect table. How to fix it

In every power break, same thing happens. ssd is off and gdisk says that the table exceeds disk limits.  I think that some ssd sectors were burnt (?) but GPT information is saying otherwise. What I can do? Gparted says will use the main table but then it shows it entirely empty.

I cannot trust ssds if they behave in that way.

However, a second question is what sectors were burnt? those at the end? at the middle? or something random?

when i press "w" in fdisk says it fixed the errors but when running again same problems.
fsck cannot be run on this disk.

If you have any idea how to solve this problem?

```
sudo gdisk  /dev/sdb 
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.9

Warning! Disk size is smaller than the main header indicates! Loading
secondary header from the last sector of the disk! You should use 'v' to
verify disk integrity, and perhaps options on the experts' menu to repair
the disk.
Caution: invalid backup GPT header, but valid main header; regenerating
backup header from main header.

Warning! One or more CRCs don't match. You should repair the disk!
Main header: OK
Backup header: ERROR
Main partition table: OK
Backup partition table: ERROR

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: damaged

****************************************************************************
Caution: Found protective or hybrid MBR and corrupt GPT. Using GPT, but disk
verification and recovery are STRONGLY recommended.
****************************************************************************

Command (? for help): p
Disk /dev/sdb: 234439535 sectors, 111.8 GiB
Model: KINGSTON SV300S3
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 17EEF8B4-C4A6-4203-BFE0-2626FAFA4FA4
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 234441614
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 2925 sectors (1.4 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048       234440703   111.8 GiB   8300  Linux filesystem


Command (? for help): w
Caution! Secondary header was placed beyond the disk's limits! Moving the
header, but other problems may occur!

Warning! Secondary partition table overlaps the last partition by
1202 blocks!
You will need to delete this partition or resize it in another utility.

Problem: partition 1 is too big for the disk.
Aborting write operation!
Aborting write of new partition table.


Expert command (? for help): i
Using 1
Partition GUID code: 0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4 (Linux filesystem)
Partition unique GUID: BAA6823F-B077-41B3-95D1-4CF4EF30FA95
First sector: 2048 (at 1024.0 KiB)
Last sector: 234440703 (at 111.8 GiB)
Partition size: 234438656 sectors (111.8 GiB)
Attribute flags: 0000000000000000
Partition name: 'Linux filesystem'


Expert command (? for help): v

Caution: The CRC for the backup partition table is invalid. This table may
be corrupt. This program will automatically create a new backup partition
table when you save your partitions.

Problem: partition 1 is too big for the disk.

Warning! Secondary partition table overlaps the last partition by
1202 blocks!
You will need to delete this partition or resize it in another utility.
```

what option to choose?

```
Recovery/transformation command (? for help): ?
b   use backup GPT header (rebuilding main)
c   load backup partition table from disk (rebuilding main)
d   use main GPT header (rebuilding backup)
e   load main partition table from disk (rebuilding backup)
f   load MBR and build fresh GPT from it
g   convert GPT into MBR and exit
h   make hybrid MBR
i   show detailed information on a partition
l   load partition data from a backup file
m   return to main menu
o   print protective MBR data
p   print the partition table
q   quit without saving changes
t   transform BSD disklabel partition
v   verify disk
w   write table to disk and exit
x   extra functionality (experts only)
?   print this menu
```

update on testdisk

```
Disk /dev/sdb - 120 GB / 111 GiB - KINGSTON SV300S37A120G

Hidden sectors are present.

size       234439535 sectors
user_max   234439535 sectors
native_max 234441648 sectors
Host Protected Area (HPA) present.



superblock 0, blocksize=4096 [tmp_ssd]
superblock 32768, blocksize=4096 [tmp_ssd]
superblock 98304, blocksize=4096 [tmp_ssd]
superblock 163840, blocksize=4096 [tmp_ssd]
superblock 229376, blocksize=4096 [tmp_ssd]
superblock 294912, blocksize=4096 [tmp_ssd]
superblock 819200, blocksize=4096 [tmp_ssd]
superblock 884736, blocksize=4096 [tmp_ssd]
superblock 1605632, blocksize=4096 [tmp_ssd]
superblock 2654208, blocksize=4096 [tmp_ssd]

To repair the filesystem using alternate superblock, run
fsck.ext4 -p -b superblock -B blocksize device

continue - efi/gpt table - advanced - superblock (otherwise dont list files)  - quit - list
```

ALL FILES ARE THERE!

UPDATE 2
I used expert mode on testdisk, then analyze then it existed the write "w" option. I pressed it.
It says that changes will become available at reboot.

In order to reload partitions, I used
`partprobe /dev/sdb` which says "cant partition be outside disk"
`kpartx -u /dev/sdb`
`hdparm -z /dev/sdb`
`blockdev --rereadpt /dev/sdb`
nothing worked.
propable changes were not yet written to disk?

UPDATE NO3
file tree is repeated forever
This has happen to me quite a few times, so when some sectors are off, some files become directories and loops
I dont know why backups of blocks / gpt tables and other fails entirely to recover the structure.
Maybe some sectors goes off and reading is looping.
Therefore, disks internally must know which sectors were off and what files were written in those sectors.

directory A --> file A file B file C.dir --> dir A -> file A file B file C.dir  --> dir A -> file A file B ......
(a file has become directory which repeats itself)
So testdisk must detect such situations and other utils and fix it.
Maybe for that reason partition is extended out of disk?

UPDATE NO4
after reboot no changes to ssd were written - same situation

UPDATE No5
I read in askubuntu
"You are caught in a loop. You cannot resize since table corrupt & you cannot fix table since it overlaps".

My conclusion:

1. There is no low level tool to force "resize partition" into boundaries when gpt is in bad situation. My disk is almost empty.
   To delete some sectors will be of no problem.

- To that account I propose, disks must contain info which files occupy which sectors as raw info (eg.fileA sectors 1 and 2).
  therefore, this info can fix corruption in part.

2. I could not find a way to put ssd disk out of read mode.
   Any try is failing. This is wrong for expert users.

- Testdisk has a write option in expert mode.
  However, it fails too.

3. Tools for data recovability in linux must fix "out of boundary GPT" and "read - only mode" even with some data corruption if no other better solution exists.

Note that all ssd statistics in smartctl -a is zero (best situation).

```
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x0033   120   120   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0/0
  5 Retired_Block_Count     0x0033   100   100   003    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours_and_Msec 0x0032   087   087   000    Old_age   Always       -       12150h+07m+16.700s
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1233
171 Program_Fail_Count      0x000a   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
172 Erase_Fail_Count        0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
174 Unexpect_Power_Loss_Ct  0x0030   000   000   000    Old_age   Offline      -       251
177 Wear_Range_Delta        0x0000   000   000   000    Old_age   Offline      -       1
181 Program_Fail_Count      0x000a   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
182 Erase_Fail_Count        0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
189 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0000   028   045   000    Old_age   Offline      -       28 (Min/Max 4/45)
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   028   045   000    Old_age   Always       -       28 (Min/Max 4/45)
195 ECC_Uncorr_Error_Count  0x001c   120   120   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0/0
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0033   100   100   003    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
201 Unc_Soft_Read_Err_Rate  0x001c   120   120   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0/0
204 Soft_ECC_Correct_Rate   0x001c   120   120   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0/0
230 Life_Curve_Status       0x0013   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       100
231 SSD_Life_Left           0x0013   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
233 SandForce_Internal      0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       5873
234 SandForce_Internal      0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       6119
241 Lifetime_Writes_GiB     0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       6119
242 Lifetime_Reads_GiB      0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       22886
```

may i suggest that disk may carry batteries for power loss?

Comment: If power cuts are problematic, I suggest buying a UPS. For the problem, follow the suggestions, backup the disk and re-partition. It might be best to format the disk to ensure correctness.

Comment: Test disk can list files and recover them. Why fdisk / gdisk cannot read the gpt table if testdisk can? and why superblock recovery does not results anything? Why test disk dont provide a way to write a proper gpt table ? No, i cannot accept such solution. Think someone of having a lot of ssd disks. even UPS can fail. data are there... This is not happen (most times with HDDs).

Comment: We can't answer "why" questions, only "how" questions. How can we help in that?

Comment: When SSDs fail they often become read-only and seem to accept writes but silently drop them on the floor without indication.

Comment: please see update no2. So how i can put ssd out of read only mode? It is not mounted. it is not used from system. why testdisk needs reboot to make changes?

Comment: If your SSD is indeed read only then that's pretty much the end of it's life. Some cell with important data can no longer be reset and the drive should be replaced. Modern SSDs are fast, but they are subject to a lottery as to whether you get a drive that will last 5 years or just 1 and they also vary wildly between manufacturers as they all compete for the lowest price in any given market. Get a new drive, copy.off what you can and throw out this one as it seems to have failed.

Comment: This read-only mode is for you to get your data out. If writing to the SSD were safe, the SSD would not have went read-only in the first place. If you managed to make it accept writes, you would risk damaging the filesystem (maybe damaging *further*, I mean maybe the filesystem is not in a healthy state even now) or killing the SSD completely.

Comment: Yes, its good that went to read only mode - my objection or question was how to make out of read only - it appears that reboot or "put out - put in" worked. Then used gparted to shrink the partition - but even succeeded to shrink it, it was not recognized by linux as valid. so i formatted again. More safing measures must taken or extra info must provided for recovability in disks.

Comment: some files become directories and loops.
I dont know why backups of blocks / gpt tables and other fails entirely to recover the structure. Maybe some sectors goes off and reading is looping. 
Therefore, disks internally must know which sectors were off and what files were written in those sectors.

Comment: "Note that all ssd statistics in smartctl -a is zero (best situation)." - This is useless info, *show us* the SMART data.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen done - updated with samrtctl data.

Comment: Yeah, looks good. "may i suggest that disk may carry batteries for power loss?": Higher end SSDs actually do in form of supercapacitors. Anyway I have hard time distilling a single answerable question from this. AISI if it's read-only the only thing you can do is rescue what can be copied. I'm gonna vote close for lack of focus.